# Looping through all cells in UICollectionView

Tags: ios, ios6, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a `UICollectionView` and i want to add animation to each cell.

Currently I'm using

```
for(UICollectionView *cell in collectionView.visibleCells){
  //add animation to cell here
}
```

But that only applies the animation to the visible cells and as soon as i scroll down and the cell is no longer visible the animation stops.

How do i loop through all the cells in the `UICollectionView`?

Comment: I am trying to achieve something similar.  But I get zero items in visible cells.  At what points this array gets populated?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would go about this in a different way, probably. If you want the cells to animate, you could set a property `shouldAnimate = YES`. Then in your `collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:` check that property and apply the animation if needed (or remove it).

After setting the property, reload only the visibleCells: `[collectionView reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:collectionView.indexPathsForVisibleItems]`.

Now, since the animation is provided when a cell is requested through the Datasource-Protocol, you also get the animation when you scroll.

Comment: Hi, one (silly) question. Does the reloadItemsAtIndexPaths go in the same collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath: just after checking the property?

Comment: No, put it in the handler for a button-press for example. Placing it in a `collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:` would put your code in a loop. not recommended.

Comment: To be clear, you'll want to set the property on the object in the collection that serves as the data source for your collectionview.